# Referencebrowserwidget in Plone 4.1.6 doesn't work

Tags: plone, porting, zope

I'm trying to port a Plone product from Plone 3 to Plone 4.1.6. Unfortunately, I am not able to use a newer version of Plone.

My Product uses the ReferenceBrowserWidget (RBW). I changed the import source from `Products.ATReferenceBrowserWidget` to `archetypes.referencebrowserwidget` as described [here](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/upgrade-guide/version/upgrading-plone-3-x-to-4.0/updating-add-on-products-for-plone-4.0/miscellaneous-import-changes).

When I start Zope/Plone and try to add a new instance of my product, I can see the typical UI of the RBW, but when I click on the "Add"-Button, nothing happens. No browser window appears and I can't set a reference.

Do you guys have any idea how to fix my problem?

Edit: This is my definition of the ReferenceField:

> from archetypes.referencebrowserwidget import ReferenceBrowserWidget
>
> ```
> [...]
>
> ReferenceField(
>     'referencedBox',
>     allowed_types = (AnotherProduct.meta_type, AndAnotherProduct.meta_type),
>     #allowed_types_method = 'getAllowedRefTypes',
>     multiValued = False,
>     required = True,
>     relationship = 'RelReference',
>     #searchable = True,
>     widget = ReferenceBrowserWidget(
>         label_msgid='label_reference_box',
>         label='Referenced box',
>         description_msgid='help_reference_box',
>         description=
>             'This is a description',
>         i18n_domain=I18N_DOMAIN,
>         allow_search = True,
>         show_indexes = False,
>     ),
> ),
> ```
>
> [...]

When I use a ReferenceWidget instead of a RBW, everything works fine (but it's quite ugly :) )

Comment: Which version of archetypes.referencebrowserwidget are you using? Are you using it for a custom content type?

Also: check for JS errors and put them here.

Comment: Hi keul. I'm using archetypes.referencebrowserwidget 2.4.11. Yes, it is for a costum content type, in which I'd like to use the RBW. How can I check for JS errors? I'm debugging with ./instance fg

Comment: Expand you question putting there how your content type is configured (I mean: the archetype definition). The JS errors are checked in the browser (open the console).

Comment: Okay I hope this is, what you asked for. I don't get any Js errors in the browser console.

Comment: A lot of recent archetypes.referencebrowserwidget are broken with `multiValued = False` configuration... but you are using an old one. I've no answer: try to upgrade to latest version (2.4.21) but I'm not sure if it works on Plone 4.1

Comment: Neither setting `multiValued = True` nor updating to 2.4.21 solved my problem. I think it has sth to do with jQuery. I replaced the relevant jQuery-method in `referencebrowser.js` with a Dummy-method and it still doesn't react...

Comment: So you don't get any output on JS console (with Chrome or Firefox) and without your change in refbrowser.js?

Comment: Hi Mathias, I don't get any JS errors neither with nor without my changes.